# Fancybox Video downloading and I have added the classes

Tags: jquery, youtube-api, fancybox

am very much a newby on here and with fancybox / web dev.

I put some code together, mainly found here. Locally my vid plays,

but when I run it of my domain (www) it want to download and not play
Anyone know why ? I have added the classes as required in a few posts
Thank you !

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
<head>
<title>MM Vid</title>

<!-- Add jQuery basic library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-lib.js"></script>

<!-- Add required fancyBox files -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Optional, Add fancyBox for media, buttons, thumbs -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>

<!-- Optional, Add mousewheel effect -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script> 


<style>

</style>
</head>
<script class="fancybox" src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>



<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fancybox({
            href: "1.mp4",
            **type: "iframe",
            class: "fancyBox",**
            beforeShow: function () {
                // Find the iframe ID
                var id = $.fancybox.inner.find('iframe').attr('id');
                // Create video player object and add event listeners
                var player = new YT.Player(id, {
                    events: {
                        'onStateChange': function (event) {
                            if (event.data === 0) {
                                $.fancybox.close();
                            } // if
                        } // onStateChange
                    } // events
                }); // YT.Player
            } // beforeShow
        }); // fancybox
    }); // ready
} // onYouTubePlayerAPIReady


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When it plays locally but not on the server is normally a path issue to your plugin library. In your case you have `fancybox/lib/...`, which may not give the exact location where the browser can download the plugin from. Try using `./fancybox/lib/...` or an absolute path (it won't hurt to learn more about absolute and relative paths ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the official [YouTube Player API Reference for iframe Embeds](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)

> The IFrame player API lets you embed a YouTube video player on your website and control the player using JavaScript. Unlike the Flash and JavaScript player APIs, which both involve embedding a Flash object on your web page, the IFrame API posts content to an  tag on your page. This approach provides more flexibility than the previously available APIs since it allows YouTube to serve an HTML5 player rather than a Flash player for mobile devices that do not support Flash.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
    <div id="player"></div>

    <script>
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
      //    after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }

      // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
      //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
      //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Read the document about it, follow the implementation. Hope it helps!